# No such file or directory -- test.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby

I have a simple test file which contains:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w

puts "Hello, Ruby!";
```

And when I try running it using `ruby test.rb` I get this error:

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- test.rb (LoadError)
```

Comment: Hi, Have you checked your working directory with 'pwd' or the contents of it with 'ls test.rb' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're running it from the same directory the file is in. If it's in a subdirectory, use `ruby subdirectory_name/test.rb`. If you use the `ls` command in your terminal, you should see the test.rb file in the directory you are in now.

Comment: Some time you get this issue even if you are on the same directory. If this is the case with you please check your command and remove extra white spaces.

Answer (score -1):

run like this

ruby test.rb.txt

Comment: You should give some explanations please.

Comment: Why do you think the file is actually named `test.rb.txt`?  Also, the question is nearly 6 years old and has an accepted answer.

Comment: I opened the file property it was showing .rb.txt file. And its working for me.